# Transforming Nested Lists Based on Patterns

Tags: java, list, groovy, collections, jvm

I'm trying to represent math expressions using nested lists, then use patterns to transform them using math identities.  For example, I want to be able to do something like this (pseudocode):

Start with `x(y+z)` in the form `['mul', 'x', ['add', 'y', 'z']]`

Apply an identity `a(b+c) = ab+ac` in the form of

```
['mul', '*1', ['add', '*2', '*3']] -> ['add', ['mul', '*1', '*2'], 
['mul', '*1', '*3']]
```

End up with `xy+xz` in the form of `['add', ['mul', 'x', 'y'], ['mul', 'x', 'z']]`

It's pretty easy in this example, but I'd like to be able to apply arbitrarily complex patterns to nested lists and allow the placeholders represented by '*n' to be able to be nested lists themselves that are arbitrarily complex.

Does anyone know of a programming language that supports something like this natively.  My weapon of choice is Groovy and I've figured out how to do it in Groovy, but I haven't tested it extensively and I was wondering if any other languages have built-in support for something like this.  I've heard that Scala has a particularly powerful collections library, so maybe it does something like this?  JVM languages are my preference.

Comment: scala's case classes and match expressions should be well-suited to the task

Comment: Thanks!  For anyone else trying to do something similar, when I started looking into case classes and pattern matching, I found a tutorial where the example is almost exactly what I was trying to do: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html